# Lynx read from file

Tags: linux, lynx

I am using Lynx to extract text from a HTML file.  How can I use Lynx to read from the file?

I tried:

```
lynx -dump file::///home/vivek/html.txt
```

and received the Alert!: Unsupported URL scheme!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got one too many colon in your URI. Try `lynx -dump file:///home/vivek/html.txt`